# Inviting *all* your friends to the Facebook Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

At the moment, using the [requests](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/) dialogue I can get a multi-friend selector come up when I want the user to invite their friends to my application (that's when the "to" parameter isn't defined). On Chrome / Safari - this is a new window, but is there any way of having all of the users friends already selected?

Otherwise - is there a way to put together a request / invite to *all* of the users friends? I've tried getting an array of all the user's friends id's into the "to" parameter, but that gives an error on FB.

I've seen a few applications on facebook that do make it possible for the user to "select all" or "invite all" of their friends - http://blog.fbsocialapps.com/2011/10/5-ways-to-tune-your-requests-to-improve-the-virality-of-your-facebook-application/

Edit - As mentioned in the comments, I'm doing this on RoR using the omniauth gem + JS SDK. I was hoping that someone may have come across this problem, and can share a solution. My intentions are not to spam, but make it easier for the user to share the application if it's worth sharing.

Comment: I'm doing this on RoR - thought someone in that community may have come up with a solution that doesn't require the FB Javascript SDK

Comment: If you've ever wanted to see just how quickly spam can be deleted from Facebook, you're sure going about it the correct way

Comment: I'm trying to make it easy for the user to invite their friends, rather than having to go through their list and click one by one. I completely understand the possibilities of spamming with this - believe me that isn't my intention, if the application is worth sharing I want to make it easier for the user to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Basically what the apps mentioned on the site you posted are doing is to use a [custom friend selector](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/games/custom-muti-friend-selector/) (See also: [Requests Pro-Tips, Pro-Tip 2: Create a Custom Multi-Friend Selector](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/games/requests/)).

This is pretty easy and straight-forward – read the list of the users friends, generate the kind of HTML you’d like them to be displayed with (a Form, an UL, IMG elements with the friends profile picture, Checkboxes to select friends, …). If you don’t want to use the JS SDK, you can do that (reading friends list + generate the HTML) server-side as well in your RoR app.

Only the part where the user can select all friends at once is probably best done client-side – loop through all the HTML elements representing the listed friends, and check the checkboxes via script. Pretty easy if you are for example using jQuery or something.

(Of course this *could* also be done by just having a checkbox labeled “send request to all friends”, and see if this is checked server-side and then send request to all friends – but that would not provide direct feedback that all friends are selected now to the user on the page.)

Then you could just send the form with all/some friends marked in it to your server-side app, generate the URL for the request dialog there and put the friend’s ids into the `to`parameter, and redirect the user’s browser to it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - that is essentially what I tried earlier, but again when I added the list of friends in the "to" parameter, it fails. The callback response states "Too many recipients" - I still don't know how some of these apps have an "Invite All"...